# Understanding queue insertion

Tags: java, collections

From Javadoc:

> Queue implementations generally do not allow insertion of null
>   elements, although some implementations, such as LinkedList, do not
>   prohibit insertion of null. Even in the implementations that permit
>   it, *null should not be inserted into a Queue*, as null is also used as
>   a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue
>   contains no elements.

How should it be interpreted? We can insert the null value into the `LinkedList` but couldn't insert it into the `Queue`, despite implementing `Queue` by `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that if you insert a null to a `LinkedList`, if you call `poll` and get `null`, you can't tell is the `Queue` is empty or if a null element was at the head of the `Queue`.

Therefore, you can insert `null` to a `LinkedList`, but you should avoid doing so if you intend to use that `LinkedList` as a `Queue`.

If you look at the implementation of `poll()` :

```
public E poll() {
    if (size==0)
        return null;
    return removeFirst(); // if the first element is null, `removeFirst()`
                          // returns null, and you might mistakenly assume
                          // the Queue is empty
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me Break it:

- `Queue implementations generally do not allow insertion of null elements`

For instance if you take `PriorityQueue` you can't insert a null value,

```
 PriorityQueue<String> prQueue=new PriorityQueue<String>();

prQueue.add("aa");
prQueue.add(null);
```

it will give a `NullPointerException`.

- `Although some implementations, such as LinkedList, do not prohibit insertion of null`

`LinkedList` also implements `Queue` but it allow null value. (it says : .. .. **generally** .. .. not restricted )

```
LinkedList<String> linkdeList=new LinkedList<String>();

linkdeList.add("aa");
linkdeList.add(null); //ok.
```

- `Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue contains no elements.`

So you can insert `null` in `LinkedList` but you shouldn't specially  if you use LinkedList as a queue
Because `poll()` method of `LinkedList`

```
Returns:
the head of this list, or null if this list is empty
```

so if you insert `null` and get `null` from `poll()` you can't say is it your inserted one or the `LinkedList` is empty.